# DateTimeFormatter doesnt work via command line

Tags: java, kotlin, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

today I have a really strange problem.
I will try to explain it as best as I can.
So the line where it fails is the third one:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(
    this.text,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE' 'dd.MM.yyyy, kk:mm 'Uhr'")
).toKotlinLocalDateTime()
```

If I execute the test via intellij it works with success:
[image: Intellij Tests]

If i execute it via the cli or in the pipeline it get this error:

[image: CMD Test/Pipeline]

The Date that i try to parse ist this line: "Mo. 19.09.2022, 08:00 Uhr"

Maybe some of you has an idea how to solve the issue?

You can find the code also here: https://gitlab.com/thw2/training-plan/api
and the CICD Pipeline here: https://gitlab.com/thw2/training-plan/api/-/jobs/3199115286

Comment: maybe it is a `Locale` problem (different default in IDE) try using `localizedBy(Locale.GERMAN)` (or similar) on the `DateTimeFormatter` (the error message is a bit strange/small... but I am not a Kotlin user, just Java)

Comment: (the weekdays are formatted differently  depending on `Locale`: "Mon" for English, "Mo." for German [my guess, obviously you should use the appropriate `Locale` ]) BTW `kk` (1-24 hour) would be strange for Germany; maybe  `HH` (0-23 hour)

Comment: Yes, HH in Germany for hours 0 - 23

Comment: (also check the `withLocale()` method of `DateTimeFormatter`, probably the better option)

Comment: Other possibilities might include different versions of Java or Kotlin, or characters that differ while looking the same (e.g. non-breaking spaces or curly quotes). But yes, the locale is more likely to be an issue — well spotted!

Comment: Oh guys you are really amazing thanks that was the solution!